# Redis vs Native Java Performance

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, algorithm, redis

I am working on a project, with a ton of Set operations per second over key value pairs, and Redis looked like a very nice approach move on.

However, I have second thoughts with this, what if the same set operations would be done using Java HashSet, infact Redis is also using the HashTable for the storage.

I assume, this would perform faster than redis, because there won't be any network, serialization and other stuffs along with RTT.

Is that right, or redis may perform better for some reason(Right now, I am only looking at performance and thread safety, rather than replication/distribution etc.)

Also, if Java, is there any nice frameworks around with some set of algorithms for the same stuffs.

Comment: What happened when you put together an example program and did some profiling yourself?

Comment: In fact, I am planning to do that itself. However, I cannot really answer, but somewhere in Google Groups, i have seen people taking about C faster than java in set operations.

Comment: For the reasons you've already mentioned, Java will outperform Redis - you should try http://trove.starlight-systems.com/ if your sets contain the data types it supports; this will increase performance further by removing the costs of boxing/unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of storing the data as POJO instead of using a database is called "Prevalence". The only available implementation in Java I'm aware is [Prevlayer](http://prevayler.org/).

*The website for [space4j](http://archive.is/QObqa), another object prevalence engine in Java, seems to be down. It looks like he project is dead.*

I agree with you that this solution is likely to outperform Redis.